# I couldn't retrieve contacts in android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am the beginner to android. I want to display the contact list in ListView. Already I have a ListView in activity_main.xml and I mentioned this in MainActivity.java. But When I run the program I got an error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.yuvi.contactsex/com.example.yuvi.contactsex.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

I got this code from website. I don't know where to change the code. Anyone help me.

- AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
  </application>
  ```
- activity_main.xml
- MainActivity.java

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

  ListView lv;
  Cursor cursor1;

  @Override
  public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
      return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
  }

  @Override
  public long getSelectedItemId() {
      return super.getSelectedItemId();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
      // create a cursor to query the Contacts on the device to start populating a listview
      cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
      startManagingCursor(cursor1);

      String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID}; // get the list items for the listadapter could be TITLE or URI


      int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}; // sets the items from above string to listview

      // new listadapter, created to use android checked template
      SimpleCursorAdapter listadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor1, from, to);


      setListAdapter(listadapter);

      // adds listview so I can get data from it
      lv = getListView();
      lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

As you are using `ListActivity` you have to add `@android` in your `id` attribute in xml:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got output. Thank you. One more Help. I need to display a Toast message(username) when the user click the a list item. Can I use a onItemClickListerner?  Whether I need to ovverride any method?

Comment: Yeah, `onItemClickListener` should do. :)

Comment: My App run in my Android Emulator. But it doesn't run in my Mobile Device? Why? Do I need to modify anything?

Comment: May be you need to add permission for to retrieve contact list. Here is the documentation - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html . Don't forget to add permission in manifest to